# Why does a laser screwdriver age The Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord

When the 10th Doctor meets up with the Master in the timeline that never happened he gets aged many many years with the Master's "Laser" Screwdriver.

[image]

How did he do that?

Do lasers affect timelords in some weird way?

Comment: Why the hell all time lords carry screwdrivers?

Comment: @SachinShekhar: They don't.  In fact, most of them didn't.  What's that you say, most of them are dead?  ...Guess they should have carried screwdrivers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Master explained this in the episode. He built the technology from the Lazarus Project into his screwdriver, including bidirectionality, so he could age someone as well as de-age them.

Now, for the bigger question, how he fit all that in a handheld-sized package, ... well, "it's bigger on the inside!" is about the only explanation we could guess at.

Comment: hehe Guess I was not paying attention that well..